# Help calculating intersection of plane and rectangular prism

Tags: geometry

How would I go about calculating the points of intersection between a rectangular prism and a plane that passes through the center of the rectangular prism?

I'm working on creating bounding boxes around 3D objects in Unity and one solution that I came up with was a plane that passes through the origin of the object's box collider. I then apply a rotation to it so that it always faces the camera.

I'm now working on the part where I need to calculate where the plane and my box intersect. I want to find the location of the 4 dots given that I know the center (in a simplified case we can just assume it's (0,0,0)) and the lengths of each edge on the box.
[Plane intersecting box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiSM3.png)

Comment: If the plane can be in any orientation, there may be six intersections with edges of the prism. If we drop the restriction of going through the center of the prism we can have three intersections.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a plane going through the center is $$n_xx+n_yy+n_zz=0$$
The intersection with a line parallel to $x$ axis, going through $(0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by $$n_xx+n_yy_0+n_zz_0=0$$ or $$x=-\frac{n_yy_0+n_zz_0}{n_x}$$
You have a single point of intersection if $n_x\ne 0$. And you must impose the condition that $|x|$ in the above equation is less than half of the $x$ width of the prism. Similar to all sides. In case $n_x=0$ you can have either no intersection with a side ($n_yy_0+n_zz_0\ne 0$), or the entire side is in the plane ($n_yy_0+n_zz_0=0$).

Comment: Does this work for any rotation of the plane? I should clarify that the plane can be at any given rotation.

Comment: Yes. You will need to calculate all possible intersections (12).

Comment: So to solve for y or z I would do something similar where I find a line parallel to the y or z axis then solve the equation from there

Comment: Correct. For the line going through $(x_0,y_0,0)$ you would get $$z=-\frac{n_xx_0+n_yy_0}{n_z}$$